# Read file into variables

Tags: parsing, batch-file

I need to parse a file in batch code. I have two pieces of information in the file.

- Fully qualified source directory (i.e. //server/share/folder)
- Fully qualified target directory

These are written to the file on seperate lines.

In my batch script, I need to read the file and put both lines into two different variables (src_dir, tgt_dir). I can change the delimiter without a problem if tabbed or spaced would be better.

I am reading up on using `for /f etc` but I don't understand how it works. 
Thank you for your pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "src_dir="
set "tgt_dir="
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in ("c:\somewhere\myfile.txt") do (
  if not defined src_dir ( 
    set "src_dir=%%~a" 
  ) else if not defined tgt_dir (
    set "tgt_dir=%%~a"
  )
)
echo %src_dir%
echo %tgt_dir%
```

In `for`,  `/f` indicates that a file content or command output is going to be processed.

`tokens=*` indicates to `for` command that no splitting on the line should be done.

`usebackq` indicates to `for` command that backquoted strings are a command to execute, and quoted string is a file to be read.

For each line readed, the code in parenthesis is executed, determining which of the two variables should receive the readed value.

Comment: Of the two suggestions, this one worked the best, so I will give you the green. However, I am still curious as to how the other one works.  

Another question as to how this works.... how does the loop know not to overwrite src_file when it loops?

Comment: @staples89, the loop does not know the variable should not be overwritten. Is the code inside the loop who handles it. A variable is considered defined if it has any content. If not, the variable does not exist. So, the `if defined` test determine if the variable has been asigned a value or not. The dbenham code uses a redirection from a file to stdin. This input is retrieved via any command that accepts data from stdin. In this case, `set /p` is used. Each time the set is executed, a line is retrieved from stdin, and as stdin is being feed from the indicated file, ...

Comment: I will pose this question to both of you -- In the near future I will have a file with 8 or 9 different lines which I will need to put into variables in a different script. How would I expand your method to work? Would I add more else statments?

Comment: @staples89, i've see now your question. dbenham solution (var=value in file) will better fit your problem. Not knowing how you get this file generated it is hard to say, but, this structure is almost a batch file. So you can go a step further and have this file with the data in it in the form `set "var=value"`, that is, a batch file and then directly get the values defined with a simple `call initValues.cmd`, avoiding the loop to read and set values.

Answer (score 3):

FOR /F is not the best option in this case. I would solve the problem as follows:

```
<"yourFile.txt" (
  set /p "src_dir="
  set /p "tgt_dir="
)

:: Show result
echo src_dir=%src_dir%
echo tgt_dir=%tgt_dir%
```

If you have empty lines between the values, then you must add an additional `set /p =` for each empty line so that it gets skipped.

---

One disadvantage of both this method and the MC ND solution is that the values must be in a particular order. If you have control over the creation of the data file, then you can create a simpler and more robust solution.

Simply prefex each value with `varname=`. For example, your data file code look like

```
src_dir=path1
tgt_dir=path2
```

Then you can use the following very simple script to read in the values. The script does not have to change if you add additional variables.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("pathSpecForYourDataFile") do set "%%A"
```

Comment: I gave this a shot. The src_dir displayed properly, but the target_dir did not, any ideas why?

Comment: @staples89 - not without more information. What do you mean by did not display properly? If no value, then there are probably bank lines that must be accounted for with extra SET /P. If incorrect value then you should show the correct value vs. what you are getting. But this technique should be very reliable.

Comment: My output looked like this: 
src_dir=\\server\share\folder 
tgt_dir='

Comment: I will pose this question to both of you -- In the near future I will have a file with 8 or 9 different lines which I will need to put into variables in a different script. In your method, I would only add lines, (set /p "var=") would I not?

I wish I could mark two as good answers...

Comment: @staples89 - Then there is probably one or more empty lines between the source and target. You would need to skip the empty lines, using `set /p =` for each empty line. The MC ND solution would work because FOR /F always skips empty lines.

Comment: @staples89 - yes, you simply add a new `set /p "varname=" for each line of input. You must be sure to add a dummy `set /p =` for any intervening blank lines.

Comment: @staples89 - See my updated answer for an alternative approach that might be easier to manage.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is parse the batch code, and read them into your 2 variables